# SQL (Sqlite) GROUP BY and COUNT

Tags: sql, sqlite

Looks like my question is not clear enough so I try to rewrite it:

I have a "file" table including among others fields "album" and "rating".
Each album has a given number of entries in the file table, each having a rating.
Rated files have a rating > 0.

What I want is to get the average rating for each album (this can be done with below query). 
BUT, I only want to include albums for which at least a given percentage (75% for instance) of its file are rated (rating > 0)

```
select album, avg(rating) AS avgRating
from file 
group by album 
order by avgRating DESC
```

Can someone help on adding the missing clause.

Comment: What do you mean by % of files ?

Comment: I mean (COUNT(*) FROM file WHERE rating>0 GROUP BY album / COUNT(*) FROM file GROUP BY album) * 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Updated, following comments):

```
select album, avg(rating) AS avgRating
from file 
group by album 
having sum(case when rating > 0 then 1 end)*1.0 / count(*) > 0.5
order by avgRating DESC
```

Comment: This one is good too. However if I change ">=0.75" to ">0.5" to compare to kcsoft's query results, your query return less entries ... dunno why yet

Comment: @RaphaelCamus: If you change ">=0.75" to ">=0.5", do you get the same number of results as kcsoft? If you change `count(*)/2` in his query to `count(*)/2.0`, do you get the same results as this query with ">0.5"? (I suspect that `count(*)/2` is being evaluated as an integer.)

Comment: his query returns 202 entries with both cases you mentioned and yours returns 114 in both cases too.

Comment: If I use this query select sum(case when rating > 0 then 1 end) , count(*), (sum(case when rating > 0 then 1 end)  /count(*)), album from file group by album I get for the division either 0 or 1 (an integer), that's the problem I think. But why ?

Comment: @RaphaelCamus: If you try changing my `sum` clause to `having sum(case when rating > 0 then 1.0 end) / count(*) > 0.5`, what do you get?

Comment: In fact it is your query that is being evaluated as an integer. The solution is select album, avg(rating) AS avgRating
from file 
group by album 
having sum(case when rating > 0 then 1 end)*1.0 / count(*) >0.5
order by avgRating DESC

Comment: With this one, I get the same results :)

Comment: Could you please edit your answer with the 1.0 change for other users ? cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you mean average rating you need `HAVING avg(rating) > 0`

Comment: No, I do not mean average rating, that is easy :) What I need is to list only albums having x% of its files with rating>0 (knowing that each album has a given number of entries in the "file" table, that is why I group by "album" though)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select album, avg(rating) AS avgRating from file  group by album  having avg(rating)>0 order by avgRating DESC
```

or

```
select album, avg(rating) AS avgRating from file  group by album where rating>0 order by avgRating DESC
```

Comment: That does not suit my needs. The first returns only albums with average >0 and 2nd makes the average only on rated files ...

Comment: You want the average rating of each album if rating>0 right ?

Comment: Aie, I can't even explain my needs in english :(

Comment: I've rewritten my question. Hope it makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    album,
    (case when sum(rating>0)>(count(*)/2) then avg(rating) else -1 end) AS avgRating
from file 
group by album 
having avgRating >= 0
order by avgRating DESC
```

count(*)/2 <-- your percentage is 50% in my example.

Comment: Have you tried this? This will return only the albums and the average ratings of their files that have a percentage of their files rated. (rating>0)

Comment: sounds great ! Only the having clause fails for some reason

Comment: sorry, I moved it before the order clause

Comment: Great! Thanks. I did not know this "case" function, looks very interesting :) One more thing though: why sum(rating>0) ? I see that it works, but why we don't have count(rating>0) (which returns the same as count(*) ) ?

Comment: the result for (rating>0) is 0 or 1. sum(rating>0) will return how many records have rating>0. the count function will count everything thats not null.